# Checking whether layer is vector or not in OpenLayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

How do I dynamically check whether a layer object belongs to the `OpenLayers.Layer.Vector` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply test the javascript [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/instanceof) operator against OpenLayers.Layer.Vector or Vector

Answer (score 1):

better way:
layer.CLASS_NAME == 'OpenLayers.Layer.Vector'

Answer (score 0):

A quick example to describe how the instanceof function works in this case:

```
map.getLayers().item(1) instanceof ol.layer.Vector
```

this code yields `true` in my case as item(1) is a vector layer

```
map.getLayers().item(2) instanceof ol.layer.Vector
```

this yields `false` in my case as item(2) is an Image layer